# Imposing restrictions on function args in clojure

Tags: clojure

I often find myself doing things like this:

```
(defn f1 [coll]
  (if (not= (count coll) 2)
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "coll must have length 2.")))
  (if (odd? (first coll))
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "first elem must be even.")))
  (if (even? (second coll))
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "second elem must be odd.")))
  (apply * coll))

(defn f2 [coll]
  (if (not= (count coll) 2)
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "coll must have length 2.")))
  (if (odd? (first coll))
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "first elem must be even.")))
  (if (even? (second coll))
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "second elem must be odd.")))
  (apply + coll))


(defn f3 [coll]
  (if (not= (count coll) 2)
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "coll must have length 2.")))
  (if (odd? (first coll))
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "first elem must be even.")))
  (if (even? (second coll))
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "second elem must be odd.")))
  (apply / coll))
```

In this trivial example I can factor the common part out:

```
(defn qc [coll]
  (if (not= (count coll) 2)
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "coll must have length 2.")))
  (if (odd? (first coll))
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "first elem must be even.")))
  (if (even? (second coll))
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "second elem must be odd."))))

(defn f1 [coll]
  (qc coll)
  (apply + coll))

(defn f2 [coll]
  (qc coll)
  (apply - coll))

(defn f3 [coll]
  (qc coll)
  (apply / coll))
```

But in real world applications this can quickly get tedious. What if the qc step of these function are all slightly different? What if I want to impose certain type restrictions?

I suppose this is one of the drawbacks of dynamic typing, but perhaps there is a way to make things easier in clojure?

Comment: You might also like: https://github.com/MichaelDrogalis/dire

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the Function form has built in [pre and post conditions](http://blog.fogus.me/2009/12/21/clojures-pre-and-post/):

```
user> (defn f1 [coll]
        {:pre  [(= (count coll) 2)
                (odd? (first coll))
                (even? (second coll))]}
        (apply * coll))
#'user/f1
user> (f1 [1])
AssertionError Assert failed: (= (count coll) 2)  user/f1 (form-init2783181480380820413.clj:1)
user> (f1 [2 2])
AssertionError Assert failed: (odd? (first coll))  user/f1 (form-init2783181480380820413.clj:1)
user> (f1 [1 2])
2
```

These don't print the nice messages, though it prints the expression that failed, so you can write that clearly enough to get the message across.